# Find values in a 2D table and return the first column value in the corresponding row Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to return the values of column A when a value is found in the column B to C. Values in table BC is unique

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| cow | 2 | 5 |
| goat | 6 | 7 |

If I enter 6 or 7 I like to get goat, if I enter 2 or 5 I like to get cow. So far vlookup, index plus match not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
=iferror(+tocol(index(if(B:C=6,A:A,)),1),"--")
```

*Change `6` within the formula to the cell hosting the value*

Comment: Thank you again. I learn something new. I use your solution and came up with how to display top row value.